# Why EnumSet is implemented as abstract class and EnumMap is implemented as concrete class?

Tags: java, enums

I was wondering, is there any reason why [EnumSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) is implemented as abstract class and [EnumMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) is implemented as concrete class?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`EnumSet` actually has two implementations - one for enums with 64 or less elements (flags indicating presence of values in the set are stored as `long`) and another one for other enums (flags are stored as `long[]`). Factory methods of `EnumSet` return one of them depending on the enum class passed in.

Such an optimization doesn't make sense for `EnumMap` (since array to store values is needed anyways), therefore `EnumMap` is a concrete class.

Answer (score 7):

`EnumSet` uses two implementations, `RegularEnumSet` and `JumboEnumSet`, depending on the size of your enum (64 elements being the threshold). The factory methods delegate to the appropriate implementation.

`EnumMap` on the other hand works the same for all enum types (it keeps an array of all enum items and an equally-sized array of values), so there's no need for an abstract class.